# How to parse xml string that contains the attribute on client using $.parseXML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing

How to parse xml string that contains the attribute on client?

I have tried this code and it does not work:

```
$.parseXML('<foo xsi:type="SendAnswerViewModel"><bar1>Stuff</bar1><bar2>Stuff</bar2></foo>')
```

But this code works fine:

```
$.parseXML('<foo><bar1>Stuff</bar1><bar2>Stuff</bar2></foo>')
```

Comment: Why does it not work? Do you get errors, if so what are they?

Comment: I'd guess your problem is more namespace than attribute related.

Comment: what are you trying to do with it. To traverse with jQuery methods try `$($.parseXML('string'))`

Comment: Sirko, thank you very much, problem was precisely in namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is invalid. You can't use a namespace without declaring it.

If you add:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://example.com/"
```

(Use the correct namespace identifier though!)

Then it will parse successfully.

```js
var x = $.parseXML('<foo xmlns:xsi="http://example.com" xsi:type="SendAnswerViewModel"><bar1>Stuff</bar1><bar2>Stuff</bar2></foo>');

alert($(x).find('bar1').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```